# Datastax Cassandra Windows Service

Tags: cassandra

This is probably really simple, but it's really annoying! When using the Cassandra.BAT file, we can set the min / max heap size via the JAVA_OPTS parameter inside said bat file; where can we do that for the Windows Service? I thought it launched Cassandra using prunsrv using the same bat file but it seems that is not the case as it doesn't pick up any of the params set there.

Thanks

Allan

Comment: Which version are you using?  Are you using Apache's, or the DataStax community or enterprise edition?

Comment: This was on the Apache 1.2.6 version; I tried the DataStax community edition, and it worked perfectly but trying to diagnose why it was different.

Answer (score 4):

Correct, prunsrv runs the java process directly (not sure starting and stopping the service would work well when using an indirect invocation via bat). You can change the settings in the registry using this location (64 bit):

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Procrun
>   2.0\DataStax_Cassandra_Community_Server\Parameters\Java\Options

You could also use this (see below), but I haven't tried that. It will append the option, so Java should ignore the prior mention of any options you append. Do NOT use --JvmOptions, as that will replace the existing complete set of options with just that new option.

prunsrv.exe //US//DataStax_Cassandra_Community_Server ++JvmOptions=-Xms2G

Comment: I've found another registry with the mentioned information: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\cassandra\Parameters\Java".